# Permission denied to Matlab folder

Tags: permissions, matlab

I tried to compile `matcaffe` by running

```
sudo make matcaffe
```

The compilation was working fine, until I got this error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/: Permission denied
Makefile:267: recipe for target 'matlab/caffe/caffe.mexa64' failed
make: *** [matlab/caffe/caffe.mexa64] Error 126
```

How to solve this  please ? I am using xubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to guess because we don't know you are running command as root or regular user but probably it's a regular user which can't access the files at path:

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/
```